# Elements (/Liquid) Tapscript opcodes

Tags: script, opcodes, liquid, covenants, elements

Related question: [What opcodes are supported on Liquid but not yet on Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/109764/what-opcodes-are-supported-on-liquid-but-not-yet-on-bitcoin)

I had seen few opcodes in the slides shared by [notgrubles](https://twitter.com/notgrubles) on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/notgrubles/status/1407040345867800578). They are:

```
OP_INSPECTCURRENTINPUT
OP_INSPECTINPUT
OP_INSPECTOUTPUT
OP_TAPTWEAK
OP_MUL64
OP_DIV64
OP_SCALARADD
OP_SCALARMUL
```

Couldn't find any of these in Bitcoin Core's source code. What does each of these opcodes do and are `OP_MUL64` `OP_DIV64` the same as `OP_MUL` `OP_DIV`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a taxonomy and details about the opcodes added in Element's Tapscript in [this document](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/master/doc/tapscript_opcodes.md#new-opcodes-for-additional-functionality). The list is longer than what you have in the OP.

As a usage example, [this document](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements-miniscript/blob/master/doc/extension_spec.md) details how Elements-Miniscript makes use of some of those opcodes.

Answer (score 0):

First 3 opcodes are transaction introspection opcodes:

> Define **OP_SUCCESS205** as **OP_PUSHCURRENTINPUTINDEX** that pushes the current input index as CScriptNum. This can be used in conjunction with input introspection opcodes for inspecting current input.

> Define **OP_SUCCESS212** as **OP_INSPECTNUMINPUTS**: Push the number of inputs as CScriptNum

> Define **OP_SUCCESS213** as **OP_INSPECTNUMOUTPUTS**: Push the number of outputs as CScriptNum

`OP_TAPTWEAK` was renamed to `OP_TWEAKVERIFY` in https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/commit/3055e8504262246c8d0e349c92b250b0daffacb9

> Define **OP_SUCCESS228** as **OP_TWEAKVERIFY** with the following semantics: Pop the three elements as: 1) 32 byte X-only internal key P, 2) a 32 byte big endian, unsigned scalar k, and 3) 33 byte compressed point Q. Abort if P, Q is invalid or k is not 32 bytes and outside of secp256k1 curve order. Abort if Q != P + k*G where G is the generator for secp256k1.

Next 2 are arithmetic opcodes:

> Define **OP_SUCCESS218** as **OP_DIV64**: pop the first number(8 byte LE) as b followed another pop for a(8 byte LE). First push remainder a%b(must be non-negative and less than |b|) onto the stack followed by quotient(a//b) onto the stack. If b==0 or a = -2<sup>63</sup> && b = -1, treat as overflow as defined above. Push 1 CScriptNum if there is no overflow.

> Define **OP_SUCCESS217** as **OP_MUL64**: pop the first number(8 byte LE) as b followed another pop for a(8 byte LE). Push a*b onto the stack. Push 1 CScriptNum if there is no overflow. Overflow behavior defined above.

These are not same as `OP_MUL` and `OP_DIV` used in [Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/90f6a623b394e65a34a1918ec67420c899c52bf4/src/script/script.h#L64).

Couldn't find `OP_SCALARMUL`, there is one crypto opcode with `SCALAR` in it: `OP_ECMULSCALARVERIFY`

> Define **OP_SUCCESS227** as **OP_ECMULSCALARVERIFY** which pops three elements from stack as described below: 1) a 32 byte big endian, unsigned scalar k. 2) Compressed EC point P, and 3) compressed EC point Q. Abort if P, Q is invalid or k is not 32 bytes and outside of secp256k1 curve order. Abort if Q != k*P

Source: https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/master/doc/tapscript_opcodes.md

Comment: OP_MUL64 and OP_DIV64 are certainly different from OP_MUL and OP_DIV, as the latter two don't exist (there used to be opcodes like that, but they were removed in 2010).